# How to create qtcreator installer from its source code?

Tags: qt-creator

I have created Qt creator plugin and used Qt creator [source code](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator) from git repo. But i could not find how to make installer package for windows at least. If you go to https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2 , you can see that Qt creator installer are created so that we can install only Qt creator. Qt is using Qt installer framework for creating installers. Where is the script for building Qt creator installer ?

Answer (score 1):

Requirement: You need 7zip installed (7z), python (2.7) and IFW.

Answer is based on Windows. you may need slightly different case with linux

My working structure is:

```
/home
 /Qt5.5.1
 /qt-creator3.6  (Qt creator  source)  
 /qtcreator3.6  (Qt creator build)
 /So-ADE
  /So-ADEDebugger   (My plugin)
```

The script is in /home

This is my script for doing the same thing: Please adapt with your own plug-in directory (Mine is So-ADEDebugger) and file structure.

Use /tmp as a build directory

```
mkdir c:\tmp
rmdir /s /q c:\tmp\out
```

Move to my plugin directory, build it

```
cd So-ADEDebugger
..\..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe
```

Add gcc to windows path (in case)

```
set PATH=%CD%\..\..\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\;%PATH%
..\..\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe
```

move to qtcreator build directory (shadow build) and install to target directory (/tmp)

```
cd ..
cd ..\qtcreator3.6
set INSTALL_ROOT=c:\tmp\out
..\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe -j 4 install
```

Copy Qt windows dll in place

```
cd ..\So-ADE
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\*.dll c:\tmp\out\bin
mkdir c:\tmp\out\bin\plugins
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\designer c:\tmp\out\bin\plugins\designer
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\iconengines c:\tmp\out\bin\plugins\iconengines
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\imageformats c:\tmp\out\bin\plugins\imageformats
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\platforms c:\tmp\out\bin\plugins\platforms
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\printsupport c:\tmp\out\bin\plugins\printsupport
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\sqldrivers c:\tmp\out\bin\plugins\sqldrivers
mkdir c:\tmp\out\lib\vcredist_msvc2013
xcopy /i/s ..\Qt5.5.1\vcredist\vcredist_msvc2013_x86.exe c:\tmp\out\lib\vcredist_msvc2013\
move c:\tmp\out\lib\vcredist_msvc2013\vcredist_msvc2013_x86.exe c:\tmp\out\lib\vcredist_msvc2013\vcredist_x86.exe
```

and reject the debug one

```
del /s c:\tmp\out\bin\*d.dll
```

Now install the plugin in target

```
cd So-ADEDebugger
..\..\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe -j 4 install
```

In my plugin i have a copy of qt-creator/dist/installer directory with my custom setup for the installer (optional pass). i copy it back to qt to build the installer with my setup

```
xcopy /i /s /y installer ..\..\qt-creator3.6\dist\installer
xcopy /i /s /y qt.conf c:\tmp\out\bin
cd ..
```

in case....

```
strip c:\tmp\out\bin\* c:\tmp\out\lib\qtcreator\plugins\*
```

Build the tar for the installer (bindist_installer target of make)

```
cd ..\qt-creator3.6
set IFW_PATH=C:\Qt\QtIFW2.0.1
..\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe bindist_installer
```

and finally package it. Changes this with your setup

```
c:\Python27\python -u .\scripts\packageIfw.py -i "C:\Qt\QtIFW2.0.1" -v 2.0.0 -a "qt-creator-windows-3.6.1-installer-archive.7z" ..\So-ADE\So-ADEdebugger.2.0.0.win
```

Comment: Nice. I was looking for this. I want to make a self-contained Qt Creator Installer that includes a compiler (MinGW) and help for C++ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives) for my students. However I can't find the installer script anymore in the Qt Creator repo.